# How to get conference call sid from partcipant call sid using rest api in Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio Rest API to get detail about participant using the participant call sid by sending request to`/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{ParticipantCallSid}`.
In response I can't find any parameter for getting conference call sid of participant. Can anyone suggest me some way to figure it out from participant call sid?

Comment: Check their REST API docs - they are well written and easy to read

Answer (score 2):

The Participants list resource is a subresource of a [Conference instance](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference) resource.

Resource URI:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Conferences/{ConferenceSid}/Participants/{CallSid}
```

You will find the first example here [returning a representation of the participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#instance-get) with both a `call_sid` and `conference_sid`.

```
{
    "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "call_sid": "CA386025c9bf5d6052a1d1ea42b4d16662",
    "conference_sid": "CFbbe46ff1274e283f7e3ac1df0072ab39",
    "date_created": "Wed, 18 Aug 2010 20:20:10 +0000",
    "date_updated": "Wed, 18 Aug 2010 20:20:10 +0000",
    "end_conference_on_exit": true,
    "muted": false,
    "start_conference_on_enter": true,
    "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Conferences/CFbbe46ff1274e283f7e3ac1df0072ab39/Participants/CA386025c9bf5d6052a1d1ea42b4d16662.json"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Twilio's Java SDK to fetch participants out of conference? It's seems simple in PHP or/and python, but I can't figure out how to do this in Twilio's Java SDK.